# Missing Data in Landsat 7 and 8 (NOT due to Scan line Error)

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, landsat-7

I have created numerous annual median composites of Landsat 7 and 8 data using Earth Engine Python API. For some reason, there are some parts of the subset showing as no data (Figure1), despite there being data available in the Landsat repository on Earth Explorer (Figure2 = screenshot from the individual image in the same year in Earth Explorer).

Any ideas as to why this data is not protruding to my annual composite?

The third image is the annual composite of Sentinel 2 image.

Here is the function within the Earth Engine Script used to generate the composite:

```
def obtain_image_median(collection, time_range, area, satname):
Parameters:
    collection (): name of the collection
    time_range (['YYYY-MT-DY','YYYY-MT-DY']): must be inside the available data
    area (ee.geometry.Geometry): area of interest

Returns:
    image_median (ee.image.Image)
 """
collect = ee.ImageCollection(collection)
if satname == ['L7']:
    ## Filter by time range and location
    collection_time = collect.filterDate(time_range[0], time_range[1])
    image_area = collection_time.filterBounds(area)
    image_2 = image_area.filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than', 40)
    image_median = image_2.median()
    return image_median

if satname == ['L8']:
    ## Filter by time range and location
    collection_time = collect.filterDate(time_range[0], time_range[1])
    image_area = collection_time.filterBounds(area)
    image_2 = image_area.filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than', 40)
    image_median = image_2.median()
    return image_median

elif satname == ['S2']:
    ## Filter by time range and location
    collection_time = collect.filterDate(time_range[0], time_range[1])
    image_area = collection_time.filterBounds(area)
    image_2 = image_area.filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE','less_than', 40)
    image_median = image_2.median()
    return image_median    

median_img = obtain_image_median('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA',
                                     inputs['dates'], ee.Geometry.Polygon(inputs['polygon']),inputs['sat_list'])
```

[image: Landsat 7 subset annual composite 2007]

[image]
[image: Sentinel 2 subet annual composite 2015]

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide the Earth Engine script which you used to generate the first image?

Comment: Hopefully, these changes are sufficient!